# Issues in commit in gerrit

Tags: git, github, gerrit, githooks, git-commit

I am trying to use gerrit and I am facing some issue while commit. When I am committing my changes and pushing it to branch then sometimes two code reviews get raised, one is mine and other one is of the person who is working on same branch and many times I get messages you are ahead of 5 commits even I did only one commit. I am using following commands:

```
git add <file_name>
git commit -m "commit msg"
git push <branch name>
```

On further reasearch I found that there may be issue due to git hook as I am not using git hook anywhere. Because of git hook gerrit is not able to distinguish between commits done by different persons and as a result many reviews get raised  in one push. Is my understanding is correct? If no, please help me why it is happening.

Also I want to ask in git hook command:

```
scp -p -P 29418 username@your_gerrit_address:hooks/commit-msg.git/hooks/
```

What this command does and what is this number 29418. Is this number is given by gerrit?

Comment: You must have a hook which generates the Change-Id automatically whenever you create a new commit. This Change-Id is something which gets generated in the log message while creating the commit and doesn't get updated when you amend the commit.

Answer (score 0):

> When I am commiting my changes and pushing it to brnach then sometimes two code reviews get raised, one is mine and other one is of the person who is working on same branch

That sounds like the intended behavior; commits that are uploaded for review aren't yet merged to your branch. The idea is that the commits are reviewed by another team member (or whatever setup your organization wants), approved, and then submitted/merged.

It's not until you've pressed the Submit button that the commit is actually present on your "real" branch. Meaning, that's when it becomes visible to anyone downloading the repository.

> many times I get messages you are ahead of 5 commits even I did only one commit

This is because your local repo has 5 commits that it doesn't know are present upstream (in the "official" branch).

First, try a "git fetch"; it will update your local copy's view of the remote (server repo), so that anything that was submitted recently will be visible to you. Essentially, this lets your local repo know that "okay, these commits are now submitted".

If that's not enough, you probably have 5 unsubmitted commits pending in gerrit.

> Because of git hook gerrit is not able to distinguish between commits done by different persons and as a result many reviews get raised in one push. Is my understanding is correct?

That seems likely. Gerrit matches commits to existing changes by the "Change-Id:" tag. If you don't have the git commit hook to add that line, gerrit may create a new change for each commit every time you push.

This is also related to the previous discussion; your local repo doesn't know that some of these commits have been submitted. So, it uploads all 5 of them each time.